# Argument of type 'CallHistoryMethodAction<[string, unknown?]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserActionType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, connected-react-router

Development environment :
react + typescript + connected-react-router

**What I intended** :
I want to use the router action asynchronously in the user action. So when login is complete I want my application to go to the main screen.

**Error Message : Argument of type 'CallHistoryMethodAction<[string, unknown?]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserActionType'**

Error code :

[image: Error code]

[image: Error code]

```
export const login = (data: { id: string; password: string }) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch<UserActionType>,
): Promise<void> => {
  await dispatch(loginRequest());
  try {
    const result = await apis.usersApi.login(data);
    if (!result.data || !result.data.id) {
      throw Error();
    }
    await dispatch(loginSuccess(result.data));
    sessionStorage.setItem('mi', result.data.id);
    await dispatch(actions.router.push('/')); <- ts error!
  } catch (error) {
    console.dir(error);
    if (!error.response) {
      await dispatch(loginFailure('서버 요청을 확인 해 주세요'));
    }
    if (error.response.status === 400) {
      await dispatch(loginFailure('id 혹은 password를 확인 해 주세요'));
    } else {
      await dispatch(loginFailure('로그인 할 수 없습니다'));
    }
  }
};
```

UserActionType code :

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../rootActionTypes';

export interface IApiKey {
  id?: number;
  api_key?: string;
  expire_date?: string | null;
}
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  is_staff: boolean;
  last_login: string;
  date_joined: string;
  api_keys?: Array<IApiKey>;
}
export interface IPolicyPWState {
  id: number;
  config_name: string;
  config_data: string;
}
export interface IUserState {
  user: IUser;
  userLists: Array<IUser>;
  userList: IUser;
  isLoading: boolean;
  addedUser: boolean; 
  deletedUser: boolean; 
  isRefreshAPI: boolean; 
  pwPolicy: Array<IPolicyPWState>;
  error: string;
}

// login action type 
interface loginRequestAction {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST;
}
interface loginSuccessAction {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS;
  data: IUser;
}
interface loginFailureAction {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE;
  data: string;
}

...

export type UserActionType =
  | loginRequestAction
  | loginSuccessAction
  | loginFailureAction
...
;
```

Root Reducer code :

```
import { connectRouter, RouterState } from 'connected-react-router';
import { History } from 'history';
import { combineReducers, Reducer } from 'redux';
import user from './users/reducers';
import board from './board/reducers';
import api from './api/reducers';
import { IUserState } from './users/users.types';
import { IBoardState } from './board/board.types';

export interface RootState {
  user: IUserState;
  router: RouterState;
  board: IBoardState;
  api: any;
}

const createRootReducer = (history: History): Reducer<RootState> =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    user,
    board,
    api,
  });

export { createRootReducer };
```

Questions : How do I create a Rootaction including a router action?

Comment: please can you share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I do not know if it helps you I also did not want to set up the your problem with me since I believe that your code snippeds are not executable.

Look here:

```
dispatch: Dispatch<UserActionType>
```

You indicate by the Generic that you have only Dispatch Types of the type UserActionType. But you have also the Type form the Connected React Router. Maybe it will work if you remove the `<UserActionType>`  generic